# simple_form datepicker-rails throws error "No input found for datepicker"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
Using Rails 4.1.8, simple forms gem and bootstrap-datepicker-rails Error is: 

    "No input found for datepicker"
```

Here's my setup: application.js:

```
    //= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

sermons.js.coffee:

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

application.css:

```
    *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
```

model:

```
    Table name: sermons
    id           :integer          not null, primary key    
    delivered_on :date
    title        :string(255)
    cites        :string(255)
    sermon_body  :text
```

_form:

```
    <%= f.input :delivered_on, as: :date, as: :datepicker %>
    <%= f.input :sermon_body, as: :wysihtml5 %>
    <%= f.submit %>   
    <% end %>
```

Error log:

```
    Rendered sermons/new.html.erb within layouts/application (41.1ms)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 53ms RuntimeError - No input found for       datepicker:
    simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:573:in `find_mapping'
     simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:502:in `find_input'
    simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:112:in `input'
    app/views/sermons/_form.html.erb:8:in `block in ... '
```

I also tried these form entries:

```
  <%= f.input :delivered_on, as: :datepicker %>
  <%= f.input :delivered_on, as: :string, class: "datepicker" %>
```

It's as though it's looking for a date I had already input, when it's a form that    requests date input.  I've read many posts here, all to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`simple_form` doesn't support `as: :datepicker` directly. You need to create a wrapper file to achieve this under `app/inputs/xyz_input.rb`.

`simple_form` also mention this ways in `readme` file [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-inputs).

You can also find similar type problem and there solutions here [How do i write a cleaner date picker input for SimpleForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007785/how-do-i-write-a-cleaner-date-picker-input-for-simpleform) & [Rails 4 + simple_form and jQuery UI. Datepicker is not working via turbolinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599266/rails-4-simple-form-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-is-not-working-via-turbolinks)

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for those resources, but they're way over my head. I just don't have the skill set to get the syntax correct. I'll make do with the three dropdowns (year, month, day) and revisit the dropdown calendar after getting other priorities settled.