# Rails 4 - why turbolinks causes datepicker stopping working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

We upgraded to Rails 4.2 from Rails 3.2 and `datepicker (jquery ui)` stops working after upgrading. Bootstrap 3 was also used in both Rails 3/4.

Here is an example of `datepicker` field in `simple_form`:

```
<%= f.input :since_date, :label => t('Since'), :as => :string %>
```

After removing the `turbolinks` from app's `application.js`, `datepicker` starts working again. Can someone explain why `turbolinks` causes the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4 + simple\_form and jQuery UI. Datepicker is not working via turbolinks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599266/rails-4-simple-form-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-is-not-working-via-turbolinks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but from a practical standpoint, I always disable Turbolinks right off the bat in any Rails application I start.  But checkout jQuery Turbolinks if you need what turbolinks offers.

According to the author of [jquery Turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks): "But if you have a large codebase with lots of $(el).bind(...) Turbolinks will surprise you. Most part of your JavaScripts will stop working in usual way. It's because the nodes on which you bind events no longer exist."

Ryan Bates talks about turbolinks issues in [railscast 390](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?view=asciicast) *Issues With Existing JavaScript Functionality*.

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle the turbo links load event and destroy and re-initialize any date pickers.

```
// Called when page first loads.
$(function(){
  $('.date-picker').datepicker();
});

// Handle turbolinks page load.
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker("destroy");
  $('.date-picker').datepicker();
});
```